# How to add the Jaybird driver to iReport

Tags: jdbc, ireport, jaybird

Hi I am trying to add the Jaybird driver to iReports without too much success. This is what I have done so far.

Copied jaybird21.dll and jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar to:

```
C:\Program Files\Jaspersoft\iReport-4.1.1\ireport\modules\ext
```

Went to Tools | Options in iReport and added JAR to the Classpath.

Went to Window | Services and added the driver.

When I try and connect with this driver (Connect Using...) using this URL:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:/GRIP/data/grip11.fdb
```

I get the following message:

```
unable to add connection, cannot establish a connection to jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:/GRIP/data/grip11.fdb using org.firebird.sql.jdbc.firebirddriver (unable to find suitable driver).
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Frontbase and when you put in the JDBC URL omit the database from the end of the URL
i.e. jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while trying to add a jtds driver to IReport. I tried adding it to the classpath from Tools --> Options but it did not work for me either.

Finally i came across this http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/500126/ireports-and-ms-sql-server

I did the following and it worked for me

1. Place the jar file jtds-1.2.jar to lib of iReport, i also added the jar to the class path of iReport.
2. extract the .dll files within jtds-1.2 downloaded zip file into the root of iReport 
   and then restart the iReport

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had some poblems too. The solution was:

1. just copy required files in /home/vladimir/iReport-4.0.2/ireport/modules/ext
2. add Firebird driver in Services -> Databases -> Drivers (you should get org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver class)
3. right click on driver and choose Connect->using and select driver you just created
4. create connection as Netbeans Database JDBC connection

If you want to setup jasperserver with this driver:

1. stop service (tomcat or whatever you use for jasperserver)
2. copy files in jasperservers /WEB-INF/lib
3. start service
4. create Datasource in iReport for repository use org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver and url like  jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.1.200/3050:c:/database.fdb?encoding=WIN1250&sql_dialect=3, 
   of course you can just click "Import from iReport"

This is for somewhat older iReport - 4.0.2 but I think it's still valid. Jasperserver is 4.2.1 and I use tomcat-7.0.19